# Group by column being less than or equal to values in that column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to be able to find, for each date, the count of unique uids grouped by max score within the group. To give an example:

Input table:

```
date                uid      score
2016-11-01          100      1
2016-11-01          100      1  
2016-11-01          200      1
2016-11-01          300      1   
2016-11-01          100      2
2016-11-01          400      2           
2016-11-02          100      1
2016-11-02          400      2
2016-11-02          500      3
2016-11-02          600      3 
2016-11-02          400      4
```

Expected query result:

```
date            unique_uid_count      score_leq_than         
2016-11-01              3                    1 
2016-11-01              4                    2
2016-11-02              1                    1 
2016-11-02              2                    2
2016-11-02              4                    3 
2016-11-02              4                    4
```

One way would be to blow up the table, listing uid with all scores less than their actual scores, and then do the COUNT DISTINCT as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid), date, score
FROM (SELECT t1.uid, t1.date, t.score FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date, score FROM tbl) t
      INNER JOIN tbl t1 ON t1.date = t.date AND t1.score <= t.score)
GROUP BY date, score
```

That seems rather inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you can solve this by calculating the *minimum* score for each `uid`/`date` and then using a cumulative sum:

```
select date, min_score as score, count(*) as exact_score,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by date order by min_score)
from (select date, uid, min(score) as min_score
      from tbl
      group by date, uid
     ) tbl
group by date, min_score;
```

Actually, this filters out scores that are not a min score.  To keep them, let's use a similar idea but with `row_number()`:

```
select date, score as score, count(*) as exact_score,
       sum(sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) over (partition by date order by score)
from (select tbl.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date, uid order by score) as seqnum
      from tbl
     ) tbl
group by date, min_score;
```

Basically, the `row_number()` ensures that each user is counted only once per day . . . but the cumulative sum then counts the user for all scores bigger than the minimum score as well.